# Moving list templates from one Site Collection to another - avoid that site columns become list colums?

Tags: 2010, list-template

When I move a list template from one Site Collection to another all the associated site columns become list columns. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to retain the site columns as site columns in the new site collection correct?

You'd want to create a feature that creates the site columns (and content type) and then creates the list with the associated (content type) site columns.  I include content type because if this is going to be used across several site collections, at some point someone is going to want that data rolled up.  Leveraging a content type will help with that.

Managed metadata might be an option as well.

Comment: Actually I want to use the "Save as list template" functionality to move a list template form one sitecol to another and retain the associated columns as site columns. I am aware of feature method but I am looking for a faster and easier method.

Comment: That isn't going to happen, a feature is the only way to do that.